# Will a try statement like this work?

Tags: c++, exception, scopes

Can I put just one all-encompassing try-catch statement in my main function that covers the entire program? Or do all functions require their own? What I mean is, will something like this work:

```
int main(){
    try{
        foo();
        bar();
    };

    catch(char* e){
        //Do stuff with e
    };
};

void foo(){throw "You'll never reach the bar.";};
void bar(){throw "Told you so.";};
```

If not, is there a similar way this can be done?

Comment: It is called pokemon exception handling.

Comment: Why don't you "try" it yourself?

Comment: @MateuszDrost: Not in `main`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I put just one all-encompassing try-catch statement in my main
>   function that covers the entire program?

Yes. `catch (...)` catches everything.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "exception caught\n";
    }
}
```

> Or do all functions require their own?

No. That would defeat the whole purpose of exceptions.

> ```
> catch(char* e){
>     //Do stuff with e
> };
> ```

This code is a result of the misunderstanding that exceptions are error messages. **Exceptions are not error messages.** Exceptions in C++ can be of any type. This includes `char*`, of course, but it is completely unidiomatic.

What you really want to do is catch `std::exception`, which **includes** an error message, accessible via the `what()` member function. Well-written C++ code only throws exceptions of type `std::exception` or derived classes. You can add `...` as a fallback for all other cases:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <exception>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (std::exception const& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "unknown exception caught\n";
    }
}
```

> ```
> throw "You'll never reach the bar.";
> ```

Consequently, throwing char arrays is wrong. It's wrong on a technical level if you expect a `char const[]` to be converted to a `char*`, but it's especially wrong on a design level. Replace the array with a dedicated exception type like [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error):

```
throw std::runtime_error("You'll never reach the bar.");
```

Comment: If you want to catch all the exceptions from main onwards check out this syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8405390/168175

Comment: @Flexo: Why? It does not seem to accomplish anything.

Comment: It makes it impossible for the "do something" to accidentally get written at the wrong scope later. At the very least it makes the intention clear.

Comment: @Flexo: Well, that "do something" should normally just be a single function call anyway, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Your example won't work because

- Declaration of `foo()` and `bar()` are not before using them.
- There is an extra semicolon between the block after `try` and `catch`.
- What is passed to `throw` is `const char*`, but you catched only `char*`.

This example worked.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo();
void bar();

int main(){
    try{
        foo();
        bar();
    }

    catch(const char* e){
        //Do stuff with e
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}

void foo(){throw "You'll never reach the bar.";}
void bar(){throw "Told you so.";}
```

Comment: I know about prototypes and all that. That's not relevant. I'm just talking about using functions that were defined elsewhere.