# Throwing an exception from C++ constructor for static [non-dynamic] objects

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I can't seem to throw an exception from a C++ constructor for objects instantiated on the stack (as opposed to a dynamic object that is allocated with the new keyword). How is this accomplished?

```
#include <stdexcept>

class AClass
{
public:
    AClass() 
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }

    void method() { }
};

int main(void)
{
    try { AClass obj; } // obj is only valid in the scope of the try block
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {

    }

    obj.method(); // obj is no longer valid - out of scope

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question? Your code clearly shows how an object on the stack can throw during construction, which is what you're asking.

Comment: How can I declare the new object, instantiate it, and still have a valid object FOLLOWING the try/catch blocks. The object needs to be declared within the try block. It's out of scope after the catch block.

Comment: You can't. If an exception propagates out of the constructor, it means the constructor fails. If the constructor fails, you don't have an object.

Comment: So I can't declare a static object (on the stack) that can catch exceptions and still be able to use that object after the catch block?

Comment: If you want to use the object after it's constructed, put the code using the object inside the try block. After all, its ability to run is conditional upon the exception not occurring.

Comment: In the code example I gave it throws an exception every time... but obviously I need one that is only going to throw an exception on failure... sorry for the misconception. I was trying to emphasize the code in the main() function rather than the class behavior itself.

Comment: `try { AClass obj; obj.method(); }`

Comment: So that's really the only way to do it? Continually nesting the blocks into the first try block? Alright, I guess I can work with that. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamRichey a) You don't need a nesting level if you don't want to, see the code in the question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620795/function-wide-exception-handling-in-c-is-it-a-bad-style . b) If you do this for every method/function you have, ie. no throwing over function boundaries, you're not using what exceptions give you in addition to normal return values. If you really want this, just use return values... (Of course, wrapping the whole function content in a `try` can make sense for some functions, but usually not for all)

Comment: Btw., a "static" object is something different than you have in your question.

Comment: Note that you might not want to catch exceptions from `obj.method()`, only from the constructor. In that case, this is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure you code a bit:

```
int main(void)
{
    try { 
        AClass obj; 
        obj.method();
    } // obj is only valid in the scope of the try block
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {

    }
}
```

If you need to catch the exception for "couldn't create an AClass object" separately from other exceptions, then throw a unique exception for that case, and add a specific `catch` clause for that type of exception:

```
class no_create : public std::runtime_error { 
    // ...
};

try {
     AClass obj;
     obj.method();
}
catch (no_create const &e) { 
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
}
catch (std::exception const &e) { 
    //  process other exceptions
}
```