# try\catch block in the main() function without brackets

Tags: c++, try-catch

Visual Studio 2015; C++ language.

I remember that I read somewhere about the entry point (i.e. `main` method) what it is possible to write this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
try{
  return 0; // I am here...
}
catch (...){
  cout << "I am 'catch'..." << endl; // This row wasn't called!
  return 1; // Oops... But the next `F10` key pressing jumps from the "try" 
  // block into this row!
}
```

I.e. at this case the `try\catch` block is located not in the brackets:

```
int main() { // start bracket
  try{
    return 0;
  }
  catch (...){
    return 1;
  }
} // end bracket
```

Both cases are compiled successfully and work too, but... In the first variant, when I am step by step pressing the `F10` key after the `try` block I get into the `catch` block also. For the second variant of code I haven't such behaviour.

Why does it happen?

Comment: If you're looking for the name, it's called a function try block. I'm not seeing your behaviour with [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89ae1763b006f80b) or with the same code on [online MSVC](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/).

Comment: And what is the statuscode (errorlevel) you get after the application runs?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335839/can-you-really-have-a-function-method-without-a-body-but-just-a-try-catch-block?rq=1

Comment: It's just a quirk of how your debugger decides which line to highlight.

Comment: Can you output something in the catch block?

Comment: Besides, function try blocks make more sense with constructors because a mere try inside the body couldn't catch those exceptions which occur during member initialization. In normal functions they have the same effect as a simple try inside the function body, I understand. Am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterSchneider, I added the `cout << "I am 'catch'..." << endl;` before the `return 1;` and I see nothing output. Of course, I added `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;` before the `main` method.

Comment: @fritzone, how can I get it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Yes, it is very similar.

Comment: Oh man that backslash is annoying! :P

Comment: On DOS use %ERRORLEVEL%. On unix do a simple `if prog; then echo ok; else echo bad; fi`(the else part is executed for exit codes != 0, because 0 indicates success). DOS: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your construction is a *function-try-block* and is defined in drafs n4296 for C++ 11 specification at 8.4 Function definitions [dcl.fct.def.general] with:

> Function definitions have the form
>
> - function-definition:
>
>   - attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> declarator virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> function-body
> - function-body:
>
>   - ctor-initializer<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement
>   - function-try-block
>   - = default ;
>   - = delete ;

and later in 15 Exception handling [except] with:

> function-try-block:
>
> - try ctor-initializer<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement handler-seq

Examples suggest that the normal usage for a function-try-block should be a ctor, but it is valid for a normal function (and main is syntactically a mere function)

It is valid and works normally, meaning that catch block is only evaluated if an exception occurs in the ctor-initializer<sub>opt</sub> on in the compound-statement. You can confirm it in your code by adding prints in your blocks or by testing return value.

In a Unix like system

```
foo
echo $?
```

should echo `0`

In a Windows system under a CMD.exe windows

```
foo.exe
if errorlevel 1 echo "Catch block"
```

should not output `Catch block`

If your debugger lets you **execute** instructions in the catch block... it is not C++ 11 conformant!

But it is known that when exiting a block, MSVC debugger puts cursor on last line of block, I assume that is is what is happening here because the last line of the function-try-block **is** last line of catch.

Comment: > should not output Catch block. <br/> Yes, I see nothing output.

Comment: @AndreyBushman: it confirms that your program correctly returns 0 to environment

Comment: I edited my code sample for pointing of the additional interesting moment.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I.e. are these the nuances of debugging of the Visual Studio?

Comment: @AndreyBushman yes, it just failed to highlight the correct line of code, but it actually executed the code you expected it to (it tried to highlight the final `}` of the function but there isn't one in this case). You can dismiss it as a display bug.

Answer (score -2):

The C++ Spec states this:

> A function-try-block associates a handler-seq with the
>   ctor-initializer, if present, and the compound-statement.
>   An exception thrown during the execution of the compound-statement or, for
>   constructors and destructors, during the initialization or
>   destruction, respectively, of the class’s subobjects, transfers
>   control to a handler in a function-try-block in the same way as an
>   exception thrown during the execution of a try-block transfers control
>   to other handlers.

There is no special use case for the usage/behaviour of a function try block in constructor or any other function.

Comment: happens...mybad..that wasn't intentional

Comment: *cough* Preview pane!